# How do I index tags and query exact matches against these tags in lucene .net?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Take this structure for example:

**Name**: John

**Hobbies**: dancing, scuba-diving, horse-back-riding, sky-diving

**Name**: Jane

**Hobbies**: motorcycle-racing, sky-diving, dancing

I am interested in indexing and querying this information. The important thing is that the query needs to be an exact match against **Hobbies**:

So, searching for "**sky-diving**" should return back both **John** and **Jane**

Searching for "**diving**" should return **0 results**, since an exact match was not found.

What would be the ideal indexing and query approach I should take to properly index Hobbies?

Comment: Add them as multiple values to the same field.  Parse them before you load.

Comment: Thank you @Frisbee, that did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them as multiple values to the same field. Parse them before you load.

Answer (score 1):

Its been some time since I've worked with Lucene, but assuming that is exactly how **Hobbies** is stored (comma + space separated), on index you would use a pattern analyzer with the following pattern ",\s*", and on query I don't think any tokenization is necessary, you can just pass the query for that field in as is.

This, of course, would be the simplest case. If you want to start handling edge-cases (casing, spaces in the tokens), you would have to take a much different approach.